# Cloud sql postgres DB create Cross project replication

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

In the Gcloud SQL Postgres database, I am currently using gcloud export and import command to create database backup in a different project. which takes a long time.
As gcloud allows us to create read replica but it creates with in the same project.
my question is?
how can i create a replica of cloud sql postgres instance in another project postgres instacne?

Comment: Did you have a look to database migration? It seems answer your question, but I never used it in real environment and I can't be sure that the right tool!

Comment: Yes i tired but found it a bit complicated. Connection issues. In the cloud sql instance in authorized ip list i have used 0.0.0.0/0 despite that i am getting connection issues. 
Even tired using logical replication and got this issue.

psql: error: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
        Is the server running on host "**.**.**.**" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?